# Can I set @media queries to target just Mac devices (Safari browser, Ipad and Iphone)

Tags: css

I am having some issues with my website rendering on Apple devices.

I know -webkit can be added to CSS to make changes. But is the prefix powerful enough to overide layouts and key content?

Can I set a logo to display a fixed width for Safari users only, (OSX, Ipad, IPhones)

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 475px)
{
.logo {
width: 75%;
-webkit-width: 200px;
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's easier to look for cross-browser-solutions for your _original problem_, than to try browser-sniffing, which is never reliable and should only be used in rare cases for Old-IE-problems.

(Also you can't just add the -webkit prefix to any attribute to make it webkit-only. It's meant for non-standard-features where the spec is in flux)

Comment: @niorad from the question I suspect he's not fixing incompatibilities but deliberately adapting his site for Apple-minded visitors.  Not sure though  :)

Comment: I am trying to overcome issues on Safari based devices. PS - I'm a 6ft leggy blonde actually

Comment: In that first case I agree that you should usually prefer fixing fundamental issues over browser-sniffing. There are very valid reasons for browser sniffing, for example to enable `position:-webkit-sticky` support on iOS, but that's at least graceful degradable. In most cases it should be avoided like the plague. As for the second part - on the internet everyone is a 62 year old fat guy smoking cigars in his underwear.

Answer (score 0):

No, media queries target the browser's observed media properties, not its platform.

You can however query the `navigator` object in Javascript, and add additional classes to the DOM this way, for example:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/ip(ad|od|hone)/i))
    document.body.className += ' ios';
```

After this you can for example:

```
 body.ios header:after {
   content:'Apple blahblah';
 }
```